# Setting Labels taking Long Time in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j 2.0.0.M05, Iam having nearly 50 million Nodes in my Database, I tried to create labels for the nodes like

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE has(n.Gender)
SET n :Person
RETURN n
```

its taking long time, how to clear the issue..?

Comment: What is: 5 Crore Nodes ?

Comment: i mean 50 Million nodes..

Comment: Aside from the batching answer given, you can probably eliminate `RETURN n` - no need to have everything returned to you if you're just adding a label. Looks like that was eliminated in @Wes's answer, hence me just pointing this out in a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting every single node in the database at the same time, in the same transaction. You'll probably need to batch it up in chunks. Start at 10k per Cypher command like this, and maybe try some larger sizes if those go well:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n:Person AND has(n.Gender)
WITH n
LIMIT 10000
SET n:Person
RETURN count(n) as number_set;
```